# No matching distribution found <package>

Tags: python, pypi

I'm trying to install [this](https://pypi.org/project/vtk/) package but I'm getting the erorr in the title along with "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: none)". Does anyone know why it won't work when it's available on PyPI?

Edit: Found out it's because I'm on the latest Python version. A commenter kindly provided an unofficial build but I'm unsure of the process in installing it. I used the link pip install --find-links wheels.pyvista.org pyvista and it seems to have installed one package called appdirs but no vtk package. If I follow the link there's build instructions but it says for Ubuntu/Linux so not sure which one I should follow on Windows.. Also, I'd like to check if wheels for Python 3.10 are forward compatible with 3.11 since I'm on the latest version

Comment: Show us the exact command you used to install the package, and the full output.

Comment: What's your current Python version?

Comment: @ZacAnger Latest version, I just installed it today.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry, I used pip install vtk, same as all the other modules.

Comment: That's the problem, VTK doesn't officially support Python 3.10 or 3.11 yet. There are unofficial builds [here](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/discussions/2064), or you can use `conda` with `conda install vtk -c conda-forge` There's an open issue on the repo [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/issues/18335).

Comment: @ZacAnger Thanks! I'm quite new to Python so slightly unsure of the process of getting the unofficial build installed. I used the link pip install --find-links wheels.pyvista.org pyvista and it seems to have installed a package called appdirs but no vtk package. If I follow the link there's build instructions but it says for Ubuntu/Linux so not sure which one I should follow on Windows.. Also, I'd like to check if you know whether wheels for Python 3.10 are forward compatible with 3.11 since I'm on the latest version

Comment: Appdirs is one of VTK's dependencies. Did the installation fail partway? VTK has about 20 dependencies, and pip should've said `Successfully installed aiohttp [long list here] yarl` when it was finished. Is there a `vtk-9.22.dist-info` in your site-packages dir? The [build instructions here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/Documentation/dev/build.md) include Windows instructions, and [here's how to build using Visual Studio](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/Documentation/dev/build_windows_vs.md).

Comment: A clarification is that vtk supports python 3.10 installation via pip on recent releases. Not yet for 3.11. See https://pypi.org/project/vtk/9.2.2/#files